# RegistrationViewModel could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am using AutoMapper. In the accounts controller I have a HTTP POST method, where the parameter inside should be:

```cs
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]RegistrationViewModel model)
```

but the problem is that when I press `Ctrl` + `.` ASP.NET does not give me recommendation to import some library. I have installed:

- AutoMapper
- AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection
- FluentValidation.

I don't know where the problem is. Please help.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post([FromBody]RegistrationViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var userIdentity = _mapper.Map<AppUser>(model);
    var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(userIdentity, model.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded) return new BadRequestObjectResult(Errors.AddErrorsToModelState(result, ModelState));

    await _appDbContext.JobSeekers.AddAsync(new JobSeeker { IdentityId = userIdentity.Id, Location = model.Location });
    await _appDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new OkResult();
}
```

Comment: I have a couple of questions. 1) I suppose you are using ASP.NET Core, correct? 2) I also suppose you are using Visual Studio, that correct too? 3) Is _"RegistrationViewModel could not be found"_ the only error you are getting? 4) Is `RegistrationViewModel` located in the same assembly as your accounts controller ? If not, please include the names of these assemblies in your question and make sure there is an existing reference between them. 5) If answering my questions still didn't solve your problem, please include full namespace for `RegistrationViewModel` and for accounts controller.

Comment: Where is the `RegistrationViewModel`  in your project? You could add the reference manually by adding its namespace at the top of the controller code.Make sure there 's no spelling mistake.

Comment: i dont know from where where should i input the RegistrationViewModel  class.I am not too much familiar with Auto Mapper and i didnt find solution guys.I've tought that it comes automatic with some already installed libraries and i can make using of it,but i cant find out which library i am missing,to use RegistrationViewModel .Some advice please

Comment: Is `RegistrationViewModel` a class in your project? Do you have the source code file with it?

Comment: @Code I do not think it is the problem of automapper.It just a viewModel created by yourself instead of included in other libraries.Please refer to https://medium.com/ps-its-huuti/how-to-get-started-with-automapper-and-asp-net-core-2-ecac60ef523f